# How to select a particular dynamic item from the list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my scenario:

1. create an id. (ID has a timestamp on it for the purpose of regression testing). For example abc_201502125566781. In other words, a unique id is created each time.
2. go to a different screen, select the same id in the pulldown menu, that was created in step 1. (Manual testing confirms that the id is available in the pulldown menu from step 1)

The following code works(not really), because it creates the new id in the search field, and grabs it, rather than the id from step 1 above. How can I tell the driver to grab the ID that was created in step 1. Thanks!

NOTE: domain_id has a timestamp assigned to it.

```
public static String domain_id = PropertyLoader.loadProperty("PVT_DOMAIN_ID") + now;
```

My code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

By xpath = By.xpath("//div[@id='overview_form']//select/option");
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//option[.='" + domain_id + "']"))); 

String getThePreviouslyCreatedsiteId = element.getText().trim();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_PAGE_SITES_PULLDOWN_SEARCH_FIELD)).sendKeys(getThePreviouslyCreatedsiteId);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_PAGE_SITES_PULLDOWN_SEARCH_FIELD)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

STEP 1:

```
/*1. From Left Navigation bar, select Setup > Sites*/
setup.setUp();
siteClickFromLeftHandMenu();

/*2. Click the +Add button*/
clickToAddNewSiteButton();


/*3. On Add/Edit Site screen, enter a valid Site ID (i.e. Site_timestamp) and click Add.*/
driver.findElement(By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_ID)).sendKeys(site_id);
verifyDisplay(site_id + "", By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_ID));

/*4. Enter the same value as domain.*/
driver.findElement(By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_DOMAIN)).sendKeys(domain_id);
verifyDisplay(domain_id + "", By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_DOMAIN));

driver.findElement(By.xpath(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_DOMAIN)).getText();

//click to add the site
clickAddToAddSiteInTheAccount();


/*5. The message "Successfully Added" is displayed.*/
verifyDisplay("Successfully added.", By.id(PvtConstants.ADD_SITE_SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED_MESSSAGE));
```

Comment: How do you create id in step 1?

Comment: using the same domain_id object

Comment: if you recall from our last issue, we selected the last one from the list, now i need to select what was created in the previous step from the same list that we worked on earlier

Comment: Yes I do. This should be relatively easy. All you have to do is just grab the same variable again. The code you posted is step 2 or 1?

Comment: the above code is for step 2

Comment: Can you provide the code for step 1as well?

Comment: So after step 4 you would probably need to store the same var to another variable and use that for next step instead of domain_id

Comment: :) how do i do this? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70825/discussion-between-saifur-and-familyguy).

Comment: As suggested by Saifur, all I had to do is remove static from the objects, so that I can access it everywhere, and worked like a charm! Thanks, Saifur!!!